# USB Stick won't mount

Tags: usb, mount

I reformatted a USB drive I had previously used as a boot drive and copied files to it. After rebooting the computer the drive now tries to mount twice and gives the error message:

Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/david/USB STICK:/dev/sdc1 already mounted or mount point busy.

The drive seems to have two names in my file mangager

USB STICK and CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-GB_DV9

How can I get the files save on USB STICK?

I'm using Linux Mint 19.3 and the USB is Formatted as Fat32

Answer (score 0):

There is a "punk" way of wiping whole disk using

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdc
```

(without number) and format it again.